# Scrolling wrapped text in an ion-list

Tags: html, css, list, ionic-framework

I've been working on a list with scrollable content, but after several tests I found that the scollbar is considering only the image but not the wrapped text for item size. This causes truncating content at the bottom of the page.

Here's my code:

```
<ion-content ng-controller="categoriesCtrl" ng-switch on="categories.length > 0" has-bouncing="false">
  <ion-refresher on-refresh="updateCategories()">
  </ion-refresher>
  <div ng-switch-when="true">
    <ion-list type="card">
      <a class="item item-thumbnail-right item-text-wrap" href="#" ng-repeat="category in categories">
        <img ng-src="{{category.photo}}" />
        <h2>{{category.name}}</h2>
        <p class="item-text-wrap">{{category.description}}</p>
      </a>
    </ion-list>
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

this is what I got, cannot scroll any further

[image: Truncated Item Demo]

Solutions?

Answer (score 4):

It appears you're using a combination of the `<ion-list>` directive with the list CSS elements. Try using the `<ion-list>` with `<ion-item>` [directive](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionList/).

```
<ion-list>
  <ion-item class="item-text-wrap item-thumbnail-right">
    <img ng-src="{{category.photo}}" />
    <h2>Name</h2>
    <p>{{description}}</p>
  </ion-item>
  <ion-item class="item-text-wrap item-thumbnail-right">
    <img ng-src="{{category.photo}}" />
    <h2>Name</h2>
    <p>{{description}}</p>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Here's the [working demo](http://play.ionic.io/app/93d4ae172b6e).

Comment: Thanks for the for the demo, that helped clarifying the problem. After some search I found that I missed using `ion-view` inside the `ion-nav-view` so the `ion-nav-header` overlapped with `ion-content`,used `has-header` class to solve overlapping between and this problem showed off, but didn't realize that I had to use `ion-view` to wrap the whole template 'or view'. Sorry my code wasn't clear enough.